# include external site in Sharepoint 'Everything' search

Tags: 2013, search-results

I added an external documentation site (publicly accessible) to Sharepoint
[Search Service Application > new content source, created a crawl rule with that URL, and verified that the site was crawled correctly.

I then created a search results page (called Reference), and filtered the results based on the path.

For some reason, when I search 'Everything', I can't find any results on that external path, but when I search Reference, I see what I'm expecting.

Sharepoint is indexing my site correctly, and is returning the results in some situations, but not others, and I don't know what the difference is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the result source used by the Search Result web part on the everything page and ensure that your result source is included. The fact that you can find items means there is just something missing.

You can create the Result Source based on the Content Source (rather than path) it won't fix your issue, but I thought you should know.

Comment: I did figure out that I had the wrong result source